# Android low-level read of SD card greater than 2GB

Tags: android, sd-card, low-level

My Android application attempts to read the physical sectors of the SD card by accessing the actual device (in my case, /dev/block/vold/179:1). (this is on a rooted phone, of course)

I'm able to open the device as a `FileInputStream`, and read data from it.  However, I can't seem to read it past the 2GB mark (my memory card is 16GB).

Is this because Android doesn't support files greater than 2GB? If that's the case, why do functions like `position()` and `skip()` accept `long` arguments??

Does anyone have advice on how to read from the device past 2GB?

Comment: It seems that this behavior only occurs in Android earlier than 3.0.  I tried running my application on a tablet (3.1), and it can indeed read the SD card (as well as internal memory) beyond 2GB...

Comment: That's correct, anything prior to honeycomb limits out at 2GB because i/o operations use lseek instead of lseek64. You can Check out the issue at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21696 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try create with a native (jni) lib and call __llseek()

```
int __llseek(unsigned int fd, unsigned long offset_high,
             unsigned long offset_low, loff_t *result,
             unsigned int whence);
```

I think you should add the prototype in your code because I doubt there is a direct include
(sys/linux-unistd.h)

of course this approach is a bit undocumented :) but you can use java after android 3 and this trick before

`man _llseek` for additional infos

Comment: I was rather hoping to avoid JNI for these purposes, but I guess I'll have to bite the bullet, since this does actually work. Thanks!