# Read-Write File greater than 2GB Android NDK (C++)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

It will sound odd to some and duplicate to some sorry for that. Actually i had not found my answer in clear words so posting a question here.

I am trying to create android ndk project where the application will read files and write to another location e.g; (copy and paste). I want to use NDK (C++) for this. But before i begin there are many questions bumping inside my little head.

**Let's start**

1. While writing a simple file (Read/write) program in c++. I found there is no 64bit equivalent seek functions to seek file size greater than 2Gb. So is it possible to Read/Write a file of size 2Gb greater in android using ndk. Or we have to use third party library to achieve this.

   I am following the this thread. 
   [JNI: Reading a text file in C code and returning to sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663467/jni-reading-a-text-file-in-c-code-and-returning-to-sdk)
2. Found certain information at:
   [Android low-level read of SD card greater than 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577098/android-low-level-read-of-sd-card-greater-than-2gb)
   which stats the use of

   ```
   int __llseek(unsigned int fd, unsigned long offset_high,
            unsigned long offset_low, loff_t *result,
            unsigned int whence);
   ```

According to NDK 14 i found this function in `#include <unistd.h>`

```
extern off64_t lseek64(int, off64_t, int);
```

Am i on correct path or is there something important i am missing.

Lastly, Is there any information about the limitation of file size or filesystem of android.

**UPDATE**

Using following headers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

For creating file

```
int fd = open(strFileName, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE);      
off64_t offset = lseek64(fd,filesize,SEEK_SET);
char textToWrite[25];
sprintf(textToWrite, "%s", "WELCOME ANDRIOD NDK 15.0");
write(fd, &textToWrite, sizeof(textToWrite));
```

For reading

```
 int fd = open(strFileName, O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE);
 off64_t offset = lseek64(fd,filesize,SEEK_SET);
 char textToRead[25];
 read(fd, &textToRead, sizeof(textToRead));
```

Tested with `filesize 4600000000`which is greater than 4 Gigs.

Now few more question arises here, as i am targeting my apps from android minSDK 15 and above.

1. do above function will work on on devices which are greater than 15 and above.
2. I have not defined `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64`
3. Is this way is safe to handle large files on android 15 and above.

Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Do you even need to seek?  You say you found the function you need.  Have you tested it?

Comment: Did you think it is a good way to copy paste 2gb file ? is not better to save path of file and use it instead of copying in your path?

Comment: actually task is bit different for the sake of understanding i  had mentioned copy and paste. I am still testing on it.

Comment: Why in C++ and JNI? You can seek 64 bits in Java with a `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: @EJP Its the requirement of my project

Comment: It is a `requirement of your project` *why?* when you can do it all in Java with `RandomAccessFile`? Who is setting these pointless counterproductive research-intensive constraints?

Comment: @EJP program is divided into two parts interface in java and core modules in c++,  one can call it security, code protection or performance whichever fits.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the `off64_t` variants were implemented until somewhat recently: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/libc.map.txt

It looks like most of it was supported by M, but some still landed in N. In other words, depending on exactly which functions you need, you may not be able to do this on any device older than N.

To make this a bit more transparent to calling code, you can define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` when building and then the headers will automatically replace the `off32_t` variants with `off64_t` when they are available in your NDK API level.

Note that to have headers new enough to do this, you'll need to be using at least NDK r14 so you can use the [unified headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r14-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md). There were some issues with unified headers in that release though, so you might also want to try r15 beta 2 that will release next week at I/O.

EDIT: Yes, the code you've posted is fine.

Comment: So, what function to use if one want to operate file size greater than 2gb and want to targert API Level 15 Above.

Comment: What have you tried? I've shown you the list of all the functions in libc mapped to the versions each function was supported. That shows `lseek` and `lseek64`, and I pointed out that you can use `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to automatically use `lseek64` in place of `lseek` on target APIs that support that.

Comment: Using ndk14 with studio 2.3 and android N emulator i have acheived the task, but few more question are still itching inside my head, so for that, I am updating my question, please have a look.